# How to clear event input after a key press?

Tags: c++, events, sfml

When I press <kbd>F</kbd>, my controller fires – everything works fine. However, when <kbd>F</kbd> is pressed twice, it fires, and after processing the first event (200ms later), it fires again, and that's not what I want. I would like to clear all the input after the first firing.

My code is:

```
sf::Event event;
while (window.waitEvent(event))
{
    if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        window.close();
    else if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
    {
        if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::F) //fire
            {
                 controleur.Shot(45, 100); //this step during 200ms
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `Window::pollEvent` instead? Your current code will freeze in that loop until the window creates an event.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question. But you might want to have a look at [`sf::Window::setKeyRepeatEnabled`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.2/classsf_1_1Window.php#aef9f2b14c10ecba8a8df95dd51c5bb73)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a variable "isShooting" to prevent your controler to shot.

```
void Controleur::Shot(int a, int b)
{
  if (!this->isShooting)
  {
    this->isShooting = true;
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

And when your actions are finished , just set the variable to false, then you can shoot again.

EDIT: nevermind, i misunderstood your problem

You could use `sf::Input::IsKeyDown` from [sf::Input](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6-fr/classsf_1_1Input.php) to see wether your key is pressed or not when computing events.

Another way to do it is flushing your event queue after the end of `Shot()` with this code

```cpp
// consumes all events in the queue
while (window.pollEvent(event));
```

But it is not a very good thing to do i think.

Comment: That is documentation for SFML 1.6 which is rather old... Chances are he is using 2.x, which only sends an event of type `sf::Event::KeyPressed` when the key is pressed (or repeated due to being held).

Comment: Then he can use the [sf::Keyboard](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php) class. Sorry for the old link.

Comment: That really depends on the use case. `sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed` is better for things that work while a key is held (e.g. acceleration in a racing game), whereas polling for a KeyPressed event is better for something that should happen only once when a key is pressed (e.g. jumping in a platformer).

Comment: Then the best solution would be to trigger a shot when it is pressed, and handle it without blocking the event loop, but he can't do it since the shot is performed in the event loop. Is flushing the event queue the best idea ? I don't think so, because it could flush events that he really wants to compute after that.

Comment: Flushing the event queue is usually a bad plan in SFML - it handles important events like requests for the window to close in addition to key presses, mouse movement, etc. Personally I'd keep tabs on the time that's passed within the instance of whatever class is shooting, and ignore the event internally until the time has been sufficiently long.